# function return different objects

Tags: iphone

I have a function(myFunction) with parameter v, I hope it can return different object depend the value of v.

something like below:

```
-(NSString*)myFunction:(NSInteger)v;
-(NSNumber*)myFunction:(NSInteger)v;
```

Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Thanks interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always return an `id`, but I think it could be confusing for whoever is using this function, as they wouldn't know what the function would return.

Depending on the context you're using the function, it would probably be better to simply have different functions

```
-(NSString*)myFunctionNSStringForNSInteger:(NSInteger)v;
-(NSNumber*)myFunctionNSNumberForNSInteger:(NSInteger)v;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to do different things depending on the value of `v` why not just switch on the value of `v` and call the relevant function with the required return type?

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. declare the function to return NSObject. Then you can return all kinds of objects that inherits from NSObject. When using the function you might have to check the type of the returned object, depending on what you want to do with the result.